# hevc_videotoolbox encoding failed

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have some downloaded My Hero Academia episodes, and I'm trying to put them on my iPad that hasn't got that much space. So, I decided to try convert them to HEVC. But, when I try to use hevc_videotoolbox for GPU acceleration. But, it doesn't work.

input command: `ffmpeg -i /Volumes/SSD\ STORAGE/MHA/S2/S02E00.mp4 -b:v 640k /Volumes/SSD\ STORAGE/MHA/S2/S02E00_0640.mp4`

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Volumes/SSD STORAGE/MHA/S2/S02E00.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.104
  Duration: 00:23:59.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2018 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1758 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 11988 tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (hevc_videotoolbox))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hevc_videotoolbox @ 0x7fd88481bc00] Error encoding frame: -12905
[hevc_videotoolbox @ 0x7fd88481bc00] popping: -542398533
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x7fd88480d800] Qavg: 52341.500
[aac @ 0x7fd88480d800] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

The file also gets created but it's empty (0 bytes)

Comment: Lazy suggestion is to try a build from the current git master branch. Assuming you used homebrew you can do that with the `--HEAD` option.

Comment: @llogan it still giving the same error

Comment: @TheCoderPro did you have any luck resolving this?  I'm encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, was able to resolve it by using 10-bit colour, just add `-pix_fmt yuv420p10le`